# MySQL Group By - Three tables with MIN function

Tags: mysql

I have searched on here to find an answer to my problem but to no avail.

I am working on a project where there are 3 tables involved, the 3 tables are flights, accommodation, and transfers.

The task is to find the cheapest price per month and per day so two separate queries.

The first query is to find the min price per month, an example:

```sql
SELECT

  sub_a.startdate,
  ROUND((
    MIN(sub_a.aprice) +
    MIN(sub_f.fprice) +
    (SELECT MIN(t.PricePP) FROM matrix.iv_transfers AS t WHERE t.PropertyID = sub_a.PropertyID AND t.Adults = sub_a.adults AND t.Airport = sub_f.arrairport AND (sub_a.startdate BETWEEN t.RangeStart AND t.RangeEnd)) +
    2.50
  )) AS TotalPP,
  ROUND(
    (
      MIN(sub_a.aprice) +
      MIN(sub_f.fprice) +
      (SELECT MIN(t.PricePP) FROM matrix.iv_transfers AS t WHERE t.PropertyID = sub_a.PropertyID AND t.Adults = sub_a.adults AND t.Airport = sub_f.arrairport AND (sub_a.startdate BETWEEN t.RangeStart AND t.RangeEnd)) +
      2.50
    ) * 1.1
  ) AS TotalAgtPP,
  sub_f.depairport,
  sub_f.arrairport,
  MONTH(sub_a.startdate) AS startdatet,
  DATE_FORMAT(sub_a.startdate, "%b %y") AS FormatDate,
  sub_a.duration,
  sub_a.PropertyID

FROM (
  SELECT

     a.aid,
     f.fid,
     a.startdate,
     f.outbounddate,
     MIN(a.aprice) AS aprice,
     MIN(f.fprice) AS fprice

  FROM matrix.iv_liveaccomm AS a
    JOIN matrix.iv_liveflights AS f USING (location, duration, adults)
  WHERE a.PropertyID = 22
    AND a.duration = 7
    AND a.adults = 2
    AND a.board = 'BB'
    AND f.outbounddate = a.startdate
    AND f.depairport = 'LHR'
  GROUP BY a.aid, f.fid, a.startdate, f.outbounddate

) AS X
  JOIN matrix.iv_liveaccomm AS sub_a ON(sub_a.aid = X.aid)
  JOIN matrix.iv_liveflights AS sub_f ON(sub_f.fid = X.fid)
GROUP BY MONTH(X.startdate);
```

The query above returns the following result:

[image]

The 2nd query is to retrieve the min price per day for a given month.

```sql
SELECT

  MONTH(sub_a.startdate) AS month_date,
  ROUND((
    sub_a.aprice +
    sub_f.fprice +
    (SELECT MIN(t.PricePP) FROM matrix.iv_transfers AS t WHERE t.PropertyID = sub_a.PropertyID AND t.Adults = sub_a.adults AND t.Airport = sub_f.arrairport AND (sub_a.startdate BETWEEN t.RangeStart AND t.RangeEnd)) +
    2.50
  )) AS TotalPP,
  sub_f.depairport,
  sub_f.arrairport,
  MONTH(sub_a.startdate) AS startdatet,
  DATE_FORMAT(sub_a.startdate, "%b %y") AS FormatDate,
  sub_a.duration,
  sub_a.PropertyID,
  h.iv_PropertyReferenceID AS PropertyReferenceID,
  sub_a.board,
  sub_a.room,
  sub_a.rating,
  sub_a.`2for1`,
  sub_a.`3for2`,
  sub_a.`4for3`,
  sub_a.`3and4`,
  sub_a.freebb,
  sub_a.adults,
  sub_a.children,
  sub_a.nss,
  CONCAT("/search/results?tkn=",DATE_FORMAT(sub_a.startdate,"%d-%m-%Y"),"|",sub_a.duration,"|","A:",da.iv_AirportID,"|A:",aa.iv_AirportID,",R:",des.iv_RegionID,"|",r.iv_ResortID,"|",h.iv_PropertyReferenceID,"|",m.iv_MealBasisID,"|",sub_a.rating,"|1|",sub_a.adults,sub_a.children,",0|0,0,0|0,0,0|LPP|",sub_a.PropertyID) AS DeepLink

FROM (
  SELECT

     a.aid,
     f.fid,
     a.startdate,
     f.outbounddate,
     MIN(a.aprice) AS aprice,
     MIN(f.fprice) AS fprice

  FROM matrix.iv_liveaccomm AS a
    JOIN matrix.iv_liveflights AS f USING (location, duration, adults)
  WHERE a.PropertyID = 22
    AND a.duration = 7
    AND a.startdatet = 6
    AND a.adults = 2
    AND a.board = 'BB'
    AND f.outbounddate = a.startdate
    AND f.depairport = 'LHR'
  GROUP BY a.aid, f.fid, a.startdate, f.outbounddate

) AS X
  JOIN matrix.iv_liveaccomm AS sub_a ON(sub_a.aid = X.aid)
  JOIN matrix.iv_liveflights AS sub_f ON(sub_f.fid = X.fid)
  JOIN global.hotels AS h ON(h.iv_PropertyID = sub_a.PropertyID)
  JOIN global.resorts AS r ON (r.iv_ResortID=h.iv_ResortID)
  JOIN global.destinations AS des ON (des.iv_RegionID=r.iv_RegionID)
  JOIN global.airports AS da ON (da.airportcode=sub_f.depairport)
  JOIN global.mealbasis AS m ON (m.MealBasisCode=sub_a.board)
  JOIN global.airports AS aa ON (aa.airportcode=sub_f.arrairport)
GROUP BY X.startdate;
```

and produces the following result:

[image]

As you can see from the first screenshot, the minimum price in June is 383 but in the 2nd screenshot, the minimum price is 386.

Why is the price different from grouping by month and date?

Thanks

Comment: What's your question  ?

Comment: Why is the price different from grouping by month and date?

Comment: Have you thought about using a view for this?  It would make reading your code much easier.

Comment: Also, what are the tables in your second query that are in the `global` schema?  You don't mention them in your question.

Comment: Your second query has an extra where condition, and inner joins to six extra tables; they're not aggregating the same data in two different ways. They are aggregating different data in different ways. _(Sidenote: splitting your join conditions so that three are in a USING and one is in the WHERE, presumably to save a little bit of typing, is just poor form.)_

Comment: It's likely the 383 value from the first does not have a row to join to in one or more of the `global` tables, excluding it from the second query's consideration.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, @Uuerdo I wasn’t using the extra where when I added the using, so I’ll be taking that out later.

Comment: Thanks, I’ll take out the extra joins on the 2nd query and see what happens.